# setTimeout в jquery некорректно считает время в неактивном окне

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

При свернутом окне в хроме время тикает медленнее примерно в 2 раза, в мозиле тестил все норм.

Answer (score 2):

В ряде ситуаций таймер будет срабатывать реже, чем обычно:

> Большинство браузеров (десктопных в первую очередь) продолжают
>   выполнять setTimeout/setInterval, даже если вкладка неактивна.
>
> При этом ряд из них (Chrome, FF, IE10) снижают минимальную частоту
>   таймера, до 1 раза в секунду. Получается, что в «фоновой» вкладке
>   будет срабатывать таймер, но редко.

[Источник](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval#%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: я вызываю функцию раз в секунду, и прибавляю к ней "1", то есть получается счетчик, так вот при свернутом хроме если ждать 20 секунд  выходит 11, а в мозиле и ie 20. То есть  хром медленнее считает.